# How do I make the foreground color of my awesome wm taskbar's selected window transparent?

Tags: lua, window-managers, awesome-wm

I'm using Awesome WM v.3.4.15. I've searched all around and only found the suggestion to add two hex digits to the hex color value of the background color of the selected window in theme.lua but after doing that and reloading it only makes it grey.

Does know what I can do to make the background color of the selected window in the top bar transparent?

Comment: Could you please add some images of the problem and desired solution as well as the parts of theme.lua that you modified in your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome/Lua uses [RGBA color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space]) space, so indeed to make color transparent you  need to add two digits after color.

The parameter you need to change is `theme.bg_focus` if I understood you correctly, to test it set it to white first `"#ffffff"` and then change the transparency: `"#ffffff00"`. If it's not that try `theme.titlebar_bg_focus` or `theme.tasklist_bd_focus`

Answer (score 1):

The two hex digits are the strength of the transparency.

`00` - full transparency
`FF` - no transparency

So you have to set your value to `#ffffff00`.